# regular expression for username

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want regular expression for username in asp.net/c# where username should be minimum 6 and maximum 15 characters. Alphanumeric characters are allowed. special characters ._ are allowed. No spaces are acceptable. The starting character should be alphabet.

I want regular expression for password where the conditions are exactly same as above but with only difference that starting character should be either alphanumeric, no special characters allowed.

Comment: not allowing special characters in passwords inherently makes them weaker, not a typical best practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

username

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9._]{5,14}
```

password

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{6,15}
```

but not allowing special chars in passwords is not wise

Comment: I was about to post something exactly like that!

Comment: In addition I would not recommend doing length checking with a regex, rather just use the regex to assert that the allowable characters are present. Check the length of the user names/passwords by using the String.Length property (you can then report an error message saying either "invalid character detected" or "password/username too long/short"

Comment: `.` is not special inside `[]`, there is no need to try to escape it.

Comment: @user653622 – I was referring to a previous revision of the answer. Outside of character classes delimited by `[]`, `.` is a special character meaning "any character"; to get a literal `.` it must be escaped as `\.`. Inside character classes `.` does not have a special meaning, so it doesn't need to be escaped.